# Reading a big structured file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io, binaryfiles

In matlab I would like to read from a structured, and rather big, file (size: 18+2048*2048 bytes), where 18 fist bytes are assigned to the header and the rest are pixel image intensities.
The concern here is the speed. As you see in the code below multiple access to the file has considerably slowed down the performance. 
Can you suggest any faster way of reading these contents from the file? e.g. reading entire thing in a buffer from which we can read using the "fread" function.

```
fid = fopen(fileName, 'r', 'b');     % 'r' readonly and 'b' big endian
a= fread(fid,1,'uint16');
b1= fread(fid,1,'uint32');
b2= fread(fid,1,'uint32');
c1= fread(fid,1,'uint32');
c2= fread(fid,1,'uint32');
img=zeros (...
for i= (b1 + 1) : (b2 + 1)
   for j= (c1 + 1) : (c2 + 1)
      img(i, j) = fread(fid,1,'uint16');
   end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just calculate the total size n from b1, b2, c1, and c2, and pass it to a single `fread(fid,n,'uint16')` call instead of looping over it. Then call `reshape` on the output to make it a 2-d array.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the image data in one go. Note the order of the elements

```
img(b1+1:b2+1,c1+1:c2+1) = fread(fid, [c2-c1+1 b2-b1+1], 'uint16').';
```

One other thing to consider is storing the data as `uint16` to avoid the integer to double conversion:

```
img = zeros(s1, s2, 'uint16');
img(b1+1:b2+1,c1+1:c2+1) = fread(fid, [c2-c1+1 b2-b1+1], '*uint16').';
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you could simply read the whole image at once like so:

```
%... read header first so that file pointer is positioned at start of image data

M = b2 - b1 + 1; % width
N = c2 - c1 + 1; % height

[A, count] = fread(fid, [M, N], 'uint16');

if (count ~= M * N) % error check for number of elements read
    disp('Error reading image file');
end

img = zeros(...);
img(b1+1:b2+1, c1+1:c2+1) = A; % offset the image as necessary
```

Comment: Be careful with the orientation